# How to check is there any character front of numbers in vba using instr

Tags: vba, excel

**Problem Description:** Find a instr(which is number) then check if the instr value carrying any character front of it or not.(for ex. 123, x123). If instr or instr with character matches the value from sheet 2 then msg box yes.

**Problem:** I can find the instr but i can't check for if the instr containing any char front of it or not. How do i check it, is it with left(chr) function or something. Here is my code but all is it doing just finding instr not the chr with the instr.

[image]   [image]

```
Sub tym()

    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, wb As Workbook, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim b, c As Range, rngNums As Range, rngText As Range
    Dim dNums, dText, rN As Long, rT As Long, t, m

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set ws1 = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set ws2 = wb.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    Set c = wb.Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

    Set rngNums = ws1.Range(ws1.Range("A1"), ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
    dNums = rngNums.Value
    Set rngText = ws2.Range(ws2.Range("A1"), ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
    dText = rngText.Value

    For rN = 1 To UBound(dNums, 1)
        b = "-" & dNums(rN, 1) & "-" (right here im defining to find instr but how do i add a function to find char front of instr)
        For rT = 1 To UBound(dText, 1)
            If InStr(1, dText(rT, 1), b) > 0 Then

               MsgBox "yes"

            End If
        Next rT
     Next rN

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you just want to find out characters in numeric string or you want to strip characters from numeric string for correct processing of data. InStr function checks the starting position of a defined character such as "," or any other character string defined.

Comment: InStr Function Treats * or ? as the actual character but not wildcard. Used ~ followed by * or ?. If your final aim is to strip characters from a numeric string then a UDF may be used. Other way could be to use some thing like this ~For i = 1 To Len(s)
        If Mid(s, i, 1) >= "0" And Mid(s, i, 1) <= "9" Then
            retval = retval + Mid(s, i, 1)
        End If
    Next`    For every character in input string, copy digits to return string.

Comment: @skkakkar na i want to find out is there any character front my instr so for ex. if i have something like 123 and next sheet i have 123 and x123 so i want my code to read 123 and x123. I uploaded some image may be will make u understand better

Comment: As already explained InStr will check first occurrence of a defined character. By x you mean it can be any character like A or B or C etc. A wild card can be use but with a defined character only. For ex. B It could be '*B' but if Sometimes it is B other times some other character, It may be difficult to use. If there is some round about way that I am not aware of.

Answer (score 1):

You can test for the presence of non-digit characters between the dashes using

```
If "xxx-x123-xxx" Like "*-[!0-9]-*" Then
```

Edit: if you just want to check for the number in question, with non-numeric characters on each side of it, then:

```
Dim v, p

v  = 123
p = "*[!0-9]" & v & "[!0-9]*"

If "xxx-x123-xxx" Like p Then 
    'matched pattern...
End If
```

Comment: i am using something like this  if instr(1,regex.Pattern([A-Z]?dtest(rt,1)),b)>0 then and now kept on getting a compiler error list separator.